# 301 redirect on URL starting with a number

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

How can I 301 redirect any URL that starts with a number between 1 - 9999, for example

domain.com/12/something/anotherthing

domain.com/378/product/widgets

domain.com/2560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)/?(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com
```

Should work but not tested, I could be braking some .htaccess rules here.

Comment: I want it to match any url where the first segment is a number between 1 - 9999

Comment: @Adrian: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Mark Byers : I see no "Comment" button :)

Comment: @Adrian: Ah yes, you need 50 rep to be able to comment.

Comment: @Alex - do you want to use PHP or .htaccess ?

Comment: Updated my first answer to be on the safe side, with an idea.